# Cut WHOLE folder if it contains .jpg files

Tags: files, directory, search

I am switching to UBUNTU from W 7. I have been using both for a while, and the perfect time has come to really switch just to Ubuntu now that my w7 crashed for good.

The big problem is, all my files are still organized in w7. I know I can still access them thru UBUNTU but who can really remember where all of them are. 
So what I need help with ( if possible ) is to search thru all folders ( and sub folders ) for a certain ( example ) .jpg (or .png, etc ) file 
and if found 
cut that folder
then paste it to another folder

I have been trying with this:

```
/media/AEA2CC99A2CC6803/DocumentsandSettings/Bon/Documents -name "*.cdr"
```

But this is as far as I've got..

Thank you all in advance, really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

Try [Find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
find /Existing_folder/*.jpg -type f -exec mv -iv \{} /New_Location \;
```

This will move all the .JPG files to a new location, verify that they were moved, and that's it.